# High Scalability in Domain-Driven Design

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository, scalability, soa, volume

I'm using DDD for a service-oriented application intended to transmit a high volume of messages between a high volume of web clients (i.e., browsers).

Because in the context of required functionality, the need for transmission outweighs the need for storage, I love the idea of relying on RAM primarily and minimizing use of the database.

However I'm unclear on how to architect this from a scalability point of view.  A web farm creates high availability of service endpoints and domain logic processing.  But no matter how many servers I have, it seems they must all share a common repository so that their data is consistent.

How do I build this repository so that it's as scalable as possible?  How can it be splashed across an array of physical machines in a manner such that all machines are consistent and each couldn't care less if another goes down?

Also since touching the database will be required occasionally (e.g., when a client goes missing and messages intended for it must be stored until it returns), how should I organize my memory-based code and data access layer?  Are they both considered "the repository"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this issue. No single answer can really cover it all...

One method to ensure your scalability is to simply **scale the hardware**. Write your web services to be stateless so that you can run a web farm (all running the same identical services, pointing to the same DB) and turn your DB into a cluster. Clustered databases run over multiple servers and work on the same storage. However, this scenario can get complicated and expensive quite quickly.

Some interesting links:

- http://scale-out-blog.blogspot.com/2009/09/future-of-database-clustering.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_farm

Another method is to **look at architecture**. CQRS is a common architectural model that ensures scalability. For instance, this architecture model -- its name stands for Command/Query Responsibility Segregation -- builds different databases for reading and writing. This seems contradictory, but if you study it, it becomes natural and you wonder why you've never thought of it before. Simply put, most apps do a lot more reading than writing, and writing tends to be a lot more complicated than reading (requiring business rule validation etc.), so why not separate the two? You can use your expensive transactional database for writing and then your cheap, maybe Non-SQL based or open source, database over multiple reading servers. Your read model is then optimized for the screens of your application(s), whereas the write model is optimized solely for writing and is in fact a DDD-based set of repositories.

There's just not enough room here to cover this option in detail, but CQRS is a good way of achieving scalability and even ease of development, once you have a CQRS framework in place. There are many other advantages to CQRS, such as ease of auditing (if you combine it with the "event sourcing" technique, which is common in CQRS-based environments).

Some interesting links:

- http://cqrsinfo.com
- http://abdullin.com/cqrs
- http://blog.fossmo.net/post/Command-and-Query-Responsibility-Segregation-(CQRS).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

If I favored RAM over database though, do you have any recommendations in that direction?  Looks like I need to create a stateless, shared nothing repository that mimics a database cluster.  A write operation, which will be common, commits changes either synchronously or asynchronously to all repository machines.  Then occasionally a process checks whether data has overstayed its welcome in RAM, and if so flushes it from all repository machines to a database.

Comment: I think RAM over database is a good choice for read-only stores. If you're going to write, RAM is only good if you can afford to lose data. Otherwise, I'd go with a transactional (ACID) store.

I do wonder why you mention "repository machines" (multiple). Do you mean a cluster, or do you mean various independent machines/services?

Comment: I mean a cluster of RAM-preferring machines that mitigates the risk of hardware failure which would, as you pointed out, result in data loss.  In the system I have planned, data would go from a client to the server, then be quickly plucked off the server by another client's pull.  Thus my data is transient and is not expected to remain on the server for more than seconds at a time.  Only in exceptional cases would data linger, at which point it would be detected and migrated from RAM to database.

Comment: During the moment between arriving at the server and hanging around long enough to be marked "for database", data could potentially be lost.  But as mentioned this moment is both brief and rare.  And I figure if I can cluster my RAM-preferring repositories, I'll be reasonably well covered.  I'm just trying to get a better idea of how this clustering should work.  And any thoughts in general regarding my proposed architecture would be much appreciated.

Comment: That would be clustering with shared RAM? I have no idea how that would work, frankly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you ready for some reading?  There are a lot of options, but I believe you should start by learning about the advantages of modern distributed NoSQL dbs, and enjoy learning from the experience learned in facebook, linkedin and other friends.  Start here:

- http://highscalability.com/
- http://nosql-database.org/